# Highlight(colorize) areas depend on size of land area on Mapbox using mapbog gl js

Tags: angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using **Angular 11**, **mapbox** library.
My problem is the following, how I can colorize country area depending on its size?

For example if the area size is 0-20 acres  - #E8474B , 21-50 acres - #26B0F9.

I can get bounding box coordinates using **mapbox** API, but there is a access problem.

Here is geojson object

```
  {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
                'type': 'MultiPolygon',
                "coordinates":[]
            }
        }
    }
```

Who can suggest me the right way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Turf.js' area function](https://turfjs.org/docs/#area) to calculate the area of each feature and then use [data-driven styling](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/data-driven-circle-colors/) to determine the [fill-color](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-fill-fill-color) of your polygons with a [case expression](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#case).

```
const features = [...];
features.forEach((feature) => {
    feature.properties.area = turf.area(feature);
});
```

The paint property of your layer should look something like this:

```
//...
paint: {
    'fill-color': [
        'case',
        ['<=', ['get', 'area'], 10],
        'red', // use red when area is <= 10
        ['<=', ['get', 'area'], 20],
        'green', // use green when area is <= 20
        ['<=', ['get', 'area'], 30],
        'blue', // use blue when area is <= 30
        'grey'  // fallback, use grey when none of the above apply
    ],
}
//...
```